# Which integral limits to choose when dealing with open intervals?

Tags: integration

Let's say I need to find out the length of an arc between the open interval $(a, b)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

1. How would I set the limits for the integral?
2. Am I still allowed to use $a$ and $b$?
3. Adding (subtracting) some small $\epsilon$ to $a$ (from $b$) seems like a dirty way to deal with this situation.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: A single point has $0$ length. Similarly, when you are calculating areas, a single line segment has $0$ area.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks, that was exactly what I thought, but I needed to be sure. :)

Comment: "Between" is the wrong word.  Saying "between $a$ and $b$" makes sense; saying "_on_ the interval $(a,b)$" makes sense.  But if you say "between the open interval $(a,b)$...." one expects "and" to follow that.  Between that interval _and_ something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can include the endpoints $a,b$ in the integral.  It doesn't affect the value of the arc length to add or drop the endpoints, so the definite integral will give the right answer.

Answer (score 8):

It is perhaps relevant to consider here the notion of [Improper integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).
For the case of an open interval $(a,b)$, with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, consider
$$
\int_a^b {f(x)\,dx}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\scriptstyle c \to a^ +\atop 
  \scriptstyle d \to b^ -} \int_c^d {f(x)\,dx} .
$$
Example: Suppose that $f$ is defined on $(0,1)$ by
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt x \sqrt {1 - x} }}.
$$
Note that $f$ is unbounded near $0^+$ and near $1^-$. Nevertheless, the integral $\int_0^1 {f(x)\,dx}$ exists as an improper integral. To evaluate it, first note that the antiderivative of $f$ is given by
$$
\int {f(x)\,dx}  =  - 2\arctan \bigg(\sqrt {\frac{1-x}{x}} \bigg) + C.
$$
Hence, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
\int_c^d {f(x)\,dx}  =  - 2\arctan \bigg(\sqrt {\frac{1-x}{x}} \bigg) \bigg|_c^d ,
$$
for any $c$ and $d$ such that $0 < c < d < 1$.
Now,
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{d \to 1^ -  } \bigg[ - 2\arctan \bigg(\sqrt {\frac{1-x}{x}} \bigg)\bigg] = -2 \arctan (\sqrt{0}) = 0
$$
(using that $\arctan$ is continuous at $0$)
and
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{c \to 0^ +  } \bigg[ - 2\arctan \bigg(\sqrt {\frac{1-x}{x}} \bigg)\bigg] =  - 2\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to \infty } \arctan (t) =  - 2\frac{\pi }{2} =  - \pi 
$$
(using that $t: = \sqrt {\frac{{1 - x}}{x}}  \to \infty $ as $x \to 0^+$). Thus
$$
\int_0^1 {f(x)\,dx}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\scriptstyle c \to 0^ + \atop 
  \scriptstyle d \to 1^ -} \int_c^d {f(x)\,dx}  = 0 - ( - \pi ) = \pi .
$$

Comment: The "\hfill"'s above should be ignored.

Comment: Why didn't you just take them out? :-)

Comment: @joriki: Thanks for the edit.